# How to scroll into View in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, view, focus

I'm developing an app using React Native. There, I want to scroll into a `View` when I press a button. I've tried something like this.

```
render() {
  return(
    <View ref={field => this.myView = field} >
      //something inside the view
    </View>
  )
}
```

then, tried

```
this.myView.focus()
```

But, it doesn't work.

I want to get the result as shown in the following GIF demo. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should store `ScrollView` ref and use `scrollViewRef.scrollTo()`

```
render() {
  return(
    <ScrollView ref={ref => this.scrollViewRef = ref}>
      <View 
        // you can store layout for each of the fields
        onLayout={event => this.layout = event.nativeEvent.layout}
      > 
        // some field goes here
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

And then when an error occurs just scroll to your field `this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: this.layout.y, animated: true });`.

**Update:**
a working example can be found [in this repo](https://github.com/nazarlitvin/rn-scroll-sample).

Comment: I'm going to give a working example, I'll back to you soon

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub repository, there is a working example. 
https://github.com/nazarlitvin/rn-scroll-sample

Comment: You can handle it with `FlatList` and `scrollToIndex`, implemented it in my demo as well.